# Failed to use MSGraph with python MSAL

Tags: python, azure, adal, office365api, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to develop an easy app that will be launch from crontab.
This App must connect to my outlook (Office360) calendar and download all event, after that i'll insert in my MariaDb.
I thought that was easy but i'm lose my mind in the last 4 days.
I try to follow Microsoft doc using NodeJs but i can't find a silent mode (a mode to request auth without signin all times) to receive token and data.
Then i try with Python in different approch, first using EWS but i read that will be deprecated in future, and in the last 2 days i'm trying with MSAL and ADAL.
The MSAL approach seem like more diffuse but i still have a this issue when i launch my script also with `acquire_token_by_username_password` or `acquire_token_by_device_flow`

`AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.`

My code is the same of the GitHub https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/tree/dev/sample
I change my config in parameter.json and insert mine:

```
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations",
    "client_id": "ClinetIdOfApp Set in Azure",
    "username": "myaccont@account.xx",
    "scope": ["User.Read","Calendars.Read"],
    "password": "MyPassword*****"
}
```

Please, anybody can tell me some suggestion for jump this rock?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **Resource owner password credential**, you need to treat your application as a **public client**.

Login Azure portal->click Azure Active Directory->click App registrations->find your application->click Authentication->change the default client type to public client.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer Tony Ju. 
I'm trying to ask to enable app from the admin :)

Comment: Sorry form my delay. I'm coming back to this issue today. Thanks a lot for your answer, it's useful. Was very hard ask to admin to enable my test app :). Thanks